# setrlimit doesn't work on restricting the maximum amount of memory

Tags: resources, setrlimit

I am learning linux resource control using `setrlimit` and `getrlimit`. The idea is to limit the maximum amount of memory that can be used for a given process:

```
#include <sys/resource.h> 
#include <sys/time.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 

int main () 
{ 
  // Define and object of structure 
  // rlimit. 
  struct rlimit rl; 

  // First get the limit on memory 
  getrlimit (RLIMIT_AS, &rl); 

  printf("\n Default value is : %lld\n", (long long int)rl.rlim_cur); 

  // Change the limit 
  rl.rlim_cur = 100; 
  rl.rlim_max = 100; 

  // Now call setrlimit() to set the  
  // changed value. 
  setrlimit (RLIMIT_AS, &rl); 

  // Again get the limit and check 
  getrlimit (RLIMIT_AS, &rl); 

  printf("\n Default value now is : %lld\n", (long long int)rl.rlim_cur); 

  // Try to allocate more memory than the set limit 
  char *ptr = NULL; 
  ptr = (char*) malloc(65536*sizeof(char)); 
  if(NULL == ptr) 
  {   
      printf("\n Memory allocation failed\n"); 
      return -1; 
  }   

  printf("pass\n");

  free(ptr); 

  return 0;  
}
```

The above code limit the memory to 100 bytes (both soft and hard). However, the `malloc` still returns without error. Is there anything wrong with the code? The output I got is:

```
Default value is : -1
Default value now is : 100
pass
```

Answer (score 2):

No, there's nothing wrong with your code. You're only wrong to assume that `RLIMIT_AS` has an *immediate* effect on `malloc()`. In a nutshell, the latter (usually, there are many variations) allocates its backing memory in chunks from heap with `brk()` or on-demand-mapped pages with `mmap()` and then carves those chunks into individual allocations. The chances are there was already enough space allocated in heap to satisfy your `malloc()` call, whereas your new `RLIMIT_AS` would affect only subsequent calls for `brk()` and `mmap()`. All in all, it is perfectly normal.

Comment: And how to enforce the limit so that the code above will not *pass* but fail with an error?